# Blender 2.8 Custom Start Window (Ctrl + u) Not working

Tags: startup-file

Ctrl + U worked in 2.79 for me, but in 2.8 it doesn't seem to work. Even if I press ctrl + u after deleting the starting cube, the next time I open Blender it's still there. Is there another way to do this now?

Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the shortcut just right clicking on the line of the function in the menu you need.

[image]

An option to assign a shortcut will appear. Then save your preferencess.

Or you can even chose 2.7 keys in key prefs.

[image]

You will have all your 2.79 shortcuts. but the best is to do a mix but it's more advanced

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do this through the menu.

To save the default scene use File > Save Startup file.

[image]

Many shortcuts have changed in 2.8. There is no default shortcut for that operation any more. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> doesn't work any more.

Comment: Thank you! That's very good to know!